# How to solve an attribute error in this particular code?

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

I got the following error when trying to run it. I had google around and found no solution to it. Anyone know how I should I write around it? Sorry I am still very new to programming.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-50d6838a5474> in <module>
     1 url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD'
     2 converter = CurrencyConverter(url)
----> 3 print(converter.convert('INR','USD',100))

AttributeError: 'CurrencyConverter' object has no attribute 'convert'
```

Here is the code

```
import requests
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CurrencyConverter():
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.data= requests.get(url).json()
        self.currencies = self.data['rates']

def convert(self, from_currency, to_currency, amount): 
    initial_amount = amount 
    #first convert it into USD if it is not in USD.
    # because our base currency is USD
    if from_currency != 'USD' : 
        amount = amount / self.currencies[from_currency] 
  
    # limiting the precision to 4 decimal places 
    amount = round(amount * self.currencies[to_currency], 4) 
    return amount

url = 'https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/USD'
converter = CurrencyConverter(url)
print(converter.convert('INR','USD',100))
```

Comment: move `convert` function inside the class `CurrencyConverter`

Comment: Your `CurrencyConverter` class doesn't contain a `convert` method. That is the reason for the error.

Comment: Indentation is very important while writing code, `convert()` should come inside of `CurrencyConverter`. Same level as `__init__`.

Comment: Yes, i got it now, thank you so much everyone. Xd

Answer (score 1):

Your question was answered in the comments, but as someone who is new to programming it may be helpful to see an example.  Indentation is import in Python, and your `convert` function is outside of your class because it is outdented from the class definition.  Stripped down, here is what your code structure should look like to include `convert` within `CurrencyCoverter`:

```
class CurrencyConverter():
    def __init__(self, url):
        pass

    def convert(self, from_currency, to_currency, amount): 
        pass
```